# Java swing - fading in a component by alpha setBackground, correct synchronization

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, multithreading

I am making my first GUI, for a project of mine. I made the first page, login for it.
Now I have a login button which should let the controller know when it's clicked and pass the username and password, but I didn't design the LoginButtonListener for that yet, just the clicking.

Now I have this `MouseListener` I made named `LoginButtonListener` which implements `MouseListener`, and this is my overwritten mouseEntered method, which should fadeIn the login button:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final LoginButtonListener b = this;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        private int alpha = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            alpha += 5;

            synchronized(b) {
                b.button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha));
            }

            if (alpha >= 255) {
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 50);
}
```

as you see I synchronize the b variable because the timer I am using is `java.util.Timer`, Timer is a own thread, so I think synchronization is required here.

Did I synchronize it correctly? or is what I am doing is wrong?

This is what happens in `mouseEntered`:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/131b2967228620e23846803840152621.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not do it right.
Never ever touch swing components from thread other than message dispatcher thread.

To do so, put code that access swing in SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable) (or invokeAndWait).

You don't need (explicit) synchronization to govern acces to swing components, because you actually work with them ONLY through one thread. Other threads just register to some queue (done through SwingUtilities) task you want to perform with GUI.

Comment: That's all I dont need any synchronization after doing invokeLater?

Comment: @BenBeri Without seeing more code, using an alpha background color could be causing issues within the Swing painting process, as Swing only knows how to paint opaque and transparent components, not translucent ones, to do that, you need to take over the painting of the their backgrounds yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Swing is a single threaded environment, you've got the right idea, but you've implemented slightly incorrectly.

Instead of `java.util.Timer`, you really should be using `javax.swing.Timer`, which will raise it's ticks within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI components from within, for example...

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            alpha += 5;
            if (alpha >= 255) {
                alpha = 255;
                ((javax.swing.Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            }

            b.button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha));
        }
    });
}
```

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

You should also be careful changing the `alpha` of the background color of any opaque component, Swing only knows how to paint opaque or transparent components, it can't deal with translucent components.  To do that correctly, you need to take over the control of the background painting...